# how can i insert multiple query?

Tags: php, oracle

Hi I'm looking for someone to help me solve my problem. i want to insert multiple query into the database. before this i used MYSQLI and it success but when i change to OCI it failed.

here is my code

```
<?php  

    //$id = 0;
    $name = $_POST['docname'];
    $pass = $_POST['docpass'];
    $ic = $_POST['docic'];
    $gender = $_POST['docgender'];
    $status = $_POST['docstatus'];
    $email = $_POST['docemail'];
    $address = $_POST['docaddress'];
    $phone = $_POST['docphone'];
    $pass = $_POST['docpass'];
    $confirmpass = $_POST['docconfirmpass'];
    $speaciality = $_POST['docspeaciality'];

    include_once ('dbconnect.php');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO STAFF(staffid, staffname, icnumber, staffgender, 
            staffstatus, staffemail, staffaddress, staffphonenumber, 
            password, confirmpass) VALUES (staffid_seq.NEXTVAL, '$name', 
            '$ic', '$gender', '$status', '$email',  '$address', '$phone', 
            '$pass', '$confirmpass')";
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO doctor(staffid, doctorspeaciality) VALUES 
            (staffid_seq.CURVAL, '$speaciality')";

    $result = oci_parse($dbc, $sql);
    $result2 = oci_parse($dbc, $sql2);
    oci_execute($result && $result2);
?>
```

The error is:

```
Warning: oci_execute() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ..
```

Comment: And the error you are getting is?

Comment: Warning: oci_execute() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in .. sorry i forgot to put my error . .

Comment: Update the question and add the error. Don't put it in comments.

Comment: oci_execute($result);oci_execute($result2);

Comment: The result of this expression is a boolean `$result && $result2`

Comment: @iqbalzamri07  `staffid_seq.CURVAL` in second query is incorrect. you have to assign it to variable first and then use it. Same for `staffid_seq.NEXTVAL`

Comment: @AlivetoDie - are you sure? That's valid Oracle SQL (well once they fix the misspelling of `currval`)